# Opengl installation using MSYS2, cannot find -lglew32

Tags: glfw, glew, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I am currently working on a project in opengl, until now I have had the luck of working on a pre-installed linux environment.
Now I have to make it work on my windows machine, I am using MSYS2 and have installed the packages below (in addition to the packages from the installation guide).

```
pacman -S gcc make mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-mesa mingw-w64-x86_64-glew mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw
```

When running my makefile I receive the errors below.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
```

I have followed all the steps in the MSYS2 guide and installed the advised packages.
I am completely new to pacman installer and MSYS2 and have no concrete idea on what causes this. Anyone who have had similar issues?

Comment: Is the glew32.lib file in a location which you have added to the linker search path?

Answer (score 1):

You're running the wrong [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).

Those packages are for `MINGW64` environment, but you're running `MSYS` environment, as indicated by the magenta text in your terminal prompt.

`MINGW64` is usually a saner choice.

Restart the terminal using `mingw64.exe` to get `MINGW64` environment. You might also want to uninstall `MSYS` gcc (the `gcc` package), to avoid accidentally using it. `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` already provides `gcc.exe`, which will be in the PATH in `MINGW64` environment.